# JAX-WS RI does not enforce XSD restrictions

Tags: validation, xsd, jax-ws, restriction

I am currently developing a few Web services using the JAX-WS reference implementation (version 2.1.7). They are contract-based, that is, the WSDL and XSD files are not generated by wsgen.

This allows me to freely use XSD restrictions to strengthen validation of values passed to my services through SOAP messages. Here are two examples of such "restricted" XSD elements:

```
<xsd:element name="maxResults" minOccurs="1">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:positiveInteger">
      <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
      <xsd:maxInclusive value="1000"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="lastName" minOccurs="0">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
      <xsd:maxLength value="25"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

I added the `@SchemaValidation` annotation to my service classes to enforce schema validation. However, JAX-WS does not enforce validation rules as expected. The behaviour is as follows:

- Missing mandatory elements are correctly reported (e.g., missing `maxResults`).
- Invalid values (e.g., character data in an integer field) are correctly reported too.
- Interval restriction violations (e.g., `maxResults` > 1000 or `maxResults` < 1) pass through the validation process without being reported and are injected into my JAXB-generated Java structures. Even negative values are considered valid despite the `xsd:positiveInteger` type!
- String length constraint violations (e.g., `lastName` length over 25 characters) are not reported either.

In other words, restrictions that appear in `<xsd:element>` tags are correctly enforced but `<xsd:restriction>` elements seem to be totally ignored by JAXB when used in a JAX-WS-based context.

I wrote a test class to check my XSD restrictions using bare JAXB (no JAX-WS). As a result, all restrictions are correctly enforced.

This gives me the feeling that there might be a bug in the usage of JAXB by JAX-WS... unless there is something I am doing incorrectly, of course...

Am I missing something fundamental here?!?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Jeff

Comment: There are multiple @SchemaValidation annotations. The one that is working for me is com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidation. I was using com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.SchemaValidation in the first place by mistake and didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found what's wrong...

In order to get my Web services to work in a JUnit context, i.e. published through `Endpoint.publish()`, I had to remove the `wsdlLocation` attribute from my `@WebService` annotations. If I don't, the `wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/SearchIndividualsV1_0.wsdl"` passed to the `@WebService` annotation clashes with the URL value passed to the `Endpoint.publish()` method, `http://127.0.0.1:9000/rpe-ws/SearchIndividuals`.

After reading Glen Mazza's Weblog (http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/soap_xml_schema_validation), **Additional Notes** section, I put back the `wsdlLocation` attribute and all restrictions are now properly enforced.

In other words, removing the `wsdlLocation` in a `@WebService` annotation does not prevent the service itself from working, but prevents restrictions declared in `<xsd:restrictions>` elements from being properly enforced. Restrictions declared in `<xsd:element>` elements, however, are still correctly enforced.

I am therefore getting back to having to solve that `wsdlLocation` compatibility problem to make my unit tests work properly, but this is way less critical than non-working validations in a production context...

Just in case... Anyone has an idea about this WSDL location incompatibility when running a Web service in a non-Web context?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Oh brother!...

In order to override the `wsdlLocation` for my JUnit tests, I created derivations of my Web service implementations that override only the `@WebService` annotation. As a result, I ran into the same problem I finally solved this morning (ref. my first answer above).

After doing plenty of tests, I figured out that it's the presence of a `@WebService`-annotated class extending my Web service implementation that prevents XSD validation from properly handling `<xsd:restriction>` tags.

To illustrate this bizarre behaviour, let's suppose I have the following classes:

```
@WebService(...)
public interface JeffWebService {...}

@WebService(..., wsdlLocation = "path/myWsdl.wsdl", ...)
public class JeffWebServiceImpl implements JeffWebService {...}
```

where `path/myWsdl.wsdl` correctly locates the WSDL. Then XSD validation works properly, i.e. the content of my first answer above is totally valid.

I now add the following class that I use in my JUnit-based `Endpoint.publish()` calls:

```
@WebService(..., wsdlLocation = "alternatePath/myWsdl.wsdl", ...)
public class TestWebServiceImpl extends JeffWebServiceImpl {}
```

that overrides nothing but the `@WebService` annotation. Then XSD validation excludes `<xsd:restriction>` tags as it used to do before specifying the `wsdlLocation` attribute at all, despite the fact that I still use the `JeffWebServiceImpl` implementation in my non-JUnit code! If I comment out the annotation in `TestWebServiceImpl`, then everything works properly again, except for unit tests, of course.

In other words, as soon as there is some class extending my Web service implementation in the classpath, the `@WebService` annotation of the most specific class overrides all others, regardless of the actual class I use in a regular Web application context. Weird, isn't it?!?

Bottom line: I will disable Endpoint-based unit tests for now. If I (or anyone reading this thread) find a clean, non-bogus way to integrate both production and JUnit configurations, I will consider putting them back in my JUnit test suite.

I hope this thread will help anyone running into the same problem solve it faster than I did...

Jeff